# Build an adjacency list from timeseries data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Let's say I have the following data in a mysql database:

`table`

- timestamp
- event
- session_id

For example, if the data looks like:

```
timestamp                 event         session_id
2014-01-01 01:01:02       Login         1234
2014-01-01 01:01:03       Like          1234
2014-01-01 01:01:05       Logout        1234
```

To get the results like this:

```
session_id       from_event        event            
1234             null              Login
1234             Login             Like
1234             Like              Logout
```

What I was thinking is to get the events as an ordered array:

```
select session_id, group_concat(event order by timestamp) 
from table 
group by session_id
```

But from there not sure how I would build the adjacency list (in sql).

Comment: A LEFT JOIN would suffice in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just use window function `lag()` to get the "previous" event of the same session:

```
select
    session_id,
    lag(event) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) from_event,
    event 
from mytable
```

In earlier versions, one alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select
    session_id,
    (
        select t1.event 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.session = t.session and t1.timestamp < t.timestamp
        order by t1.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    ) from_event,
    event
from mytable t
```

Comment: mysql8.0 is light years ahead of/better than what I'm on...